# Why does TObjectList<T>.Clear not free objects?

Tags: delphi, generics, collections, delphi-xe

I just noticed that

```
var
  ObjList : TObjectList <TMyObject>;
...
ObjList := TObjectList <TMyObject>.Create (True);
ObjList.Add (TMyObject.Create);
ObjList.Clear;
```

does not free the object. Looking at the source code it seems that no `cnRemoved` notification is triggered in `Clear` (inherited from `TList <T>`).

**My question:** Is this intentional? Is there any reason why one does not want to get these notifications in the case of `Clear`? Or can this be considered as a bug in the collection classes?

**EDIT**

Turns out that a I put the line

```
inherited Create;
```

on the top of `TMyObject` destructor, which was supposed to go into the constructor. This is why I got memory leaks reported that looked like the `TObjectList` was not freeing the items. And a look at the source convinced me (I was trapped by the `Count` property). Thanks for your help anyway!

Comment: Wild guess: Have you marked `TMyObject.Destroy` as `override`?

Comment: How are you measuring that the object doesn't get freed?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The list frees owned objects when you call `.Clear`. You've got a testing error. The code sample below, written on Delphi XE, displays this:

```
Calling CLEAR
Object deleted.
Object deleted.
After CLEAR. Press ENTER to free L and Exit.
```

---

The code in `TList<T>.Clear` is deceiving, because `Count` is actually a property. Look at `SetCount()`, then look at `DeleteRange()` and you'll see the code for `Notify(oldItems[i], cnRemoved)` at the end of the `DeleteRange` procedure.

---

```
program Project3;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses SysUtils, Generics.Collections;

type
  TDelObject = class
  public
    destructor Destroy;override;
  end;

{ TDelObject }

destructor TDelObject.Destroy;
begin
  WriteLn('Object deleted.');
  inherited;
end;

var L:TObjectList<TDelObject>;

begin
  L := TObjectList<TDelObject>.Create(True);
  L.Add(TDelObject.Create);
  L.Add(TDelObject.Create);
  WriteLn('Calling CLEAR');
  L.Clear;
  WriteLn('After CLEAR. Press ENTER to free L and Exit.');
  Readln;
  L.Free;
end.
```

Answer (score 9):

`TList<T>.Clear` calls `DeleteRange` to do the work. The last part of `DeleteRange` runs around all the items calling `Notify` passing `cnRemoved`.

Your analysis of the code is thus incorrect.  The `cnRemoved` notification is duly delivered and owned objects are freed.

Comment: Ehh. Quote from my answer, 33 minutes earlier to yours: `"The code in TList<T>.Clear is deceiving, because Count is actually a property. Look at SetCount(), then look at DeleteRange() and you'll see the code for Notify(oldItems[i], cnRemoved) at the end of the DeleteRange procedure."`

Comment: @Cosmin I know. But your answer has loads of code that clutters up that message. As you know I like concise answers.

Comment: Your logic is good, and your answer is correct, but I prefer Cosmin's answer because it has sample code. Nevertheless I +1 on both.

Comment: @Warren @Cosmin I don't see the need for the code. If one is going to add code then surely it would be better to check for `cnRemoved` notification since that was what OP actually said was missing. And yes I know that one follows from the other.

Comment: @CosminPrund, @ warren  You are both good boys.  Thanks for the thoroughness!